# ReactJS JSX Use Shorthand to Perform Multiple Executions

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I understand a shorthand can be used to return a single execution, but is there a way to make a shorthand return multiple executions?

Take the following example (working):

```
import React from 'react';

const CompName = () => {
  const condition = true;
  return (
    <div>{condition && console.log("one")}</div>
  )
}

export default CompName;
```

**Output:**
one

---

Now I want to execute two console logs if the condition is true:

```
import React from 'react';

const CompName = () => {
  const condition = true;
  return (
    <div>{condition && (console.log("one") && console.log("two"))}</div>
  )
}

export default CompName;
```

**Output:**
one

***Expected Output:***
one
two

Anyone have any idea on the syntax I should be using to get the expected output?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think i got it working. I needed to use the OR instead of the AND.

change:

```
 condition && (console.log("one") && console.log("two"))
```

to:

```
 condition && (console.log("one") || console.log("two"))
```

I believe the reason for this was the shorthand is looking for a true/false return value. And a function call returning nothing is falsey, therefor the 2nd execution never takes place.

I'll leave this up here in case anyone else runs into this.

Edit:

Although the above works, shorthand's should NEVER BE USED this way.

The reason is lets say those two executions are function calls, and the first execution is changed to return `true`. This means the 2nd execution will never happen.

This means later down the road you can introduce a bug that will become very hard to trace.

Ultimately, it's just better to use the following when you have MORE THAN ONE execution needing to perform:

```
if(condition){console.log("foo"); console.log("bar");}
```

This becomes much easier to find in the code, if the bug is ever introduced.

Comment: This will only work if the return of the first function is falsy. If you try to apply this to other types of function calls, it may be unpredictable. I would highly discourage you from using this pattern.

Comment: What you're actually referring to is called "short-circuit evaluation" (you can read about it [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Logical_Operators)).

Comment: @BrianThompson I just had a discussion with my mentor about this and I agree 100%. I will update the answer on when shorthands like this should only be used, and what should be used instead.

Answer (score 0):

you can use comma operator

```
import React from 'react';

const CompName = () => {
  const condition = true;
  return (
    <div>{condition && (console.log("one"), console.log("two"))}</div>
  )
}

export default CompName;
```

```js
ReactDOM.render( <CompName/>, root )

function CompName () {
  const condition = true;
  return (
    <div>
      {condition && (console.log("one"), console.log("two"))}</div>
  )
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/16.6.3/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/16.6.3/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>
<div id='root'></div>
```

Comment: I already tried this earlier and it didn't work for me. It loads with an error.

Comment: @FiddleFreak I'd added a react example